# iOS App for Live Concert Ideas

Tags: ios, audio, app-store, light

I want to make an App for concert. Basically this will serve a lights sync on the music played in the concert. The flashing of lights should be in sync in the beat or music at the concert.

Something like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dan-deacon/id536378735?mt=8

Question is

1. Is the app listening to the music thru the microphone?
2. If it is listening, how does it know when to flash the lights based on the beat of the music or the music itself?
3. In the example app I posted it's not using any wifi or mobile data so does it mean that it's standalone and does #1 and #2?

I have this question coz I'm new to app development. I want to do those feature but my idea is that there is a server which we control that will just send the lights flashing pattern on those apps, my concern is that if there's were 100,000 people in the event, provided the all have a wifi connection, will the sending of flashing lights pattern be a problem espcially you are sending hundred thousands of commands at the same time? I would prefer it to be in offline mode but how till it exactly work?

Answer (score 0):

That is an amazing app. You need to synchronize your apps to the musik and maybe the apps among them selfs.

I picked some links for you:

http://content.iospress.com/articles/journal-of-embedded-computing/jec00021

http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~cdgill/PDF/RTSS08.pdf

http://blog.trifork.com/2013/02/18/build-build-massively-scalable-soft-real-time-systems-with-erlang/

In praxis i can imagine that the user starts playing the song and the app synchonize by the recorded sounds...